# For $k$ a field, $k[x]$ is Noetherian but not Artinian?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, noetherian, artinian

I have a question regarding some Commutative Algebra facts. 
I am using the book *A Course in Commutative Algebra* by Gregor Kemper. On page 24 he states that if $k$ is a field, the polynomial ring $k[x]$ is Noetherian, and not Artinian. And in theorem 2.8 he states:

Let $R$ be a ring. Then the following statements are equivalent:

$R$ is Artinian $\Leftrightarrow$ $R$ is Noetherian and every prime ideal of $R$ is maximal.

Now I learned in my basic algebra courses that if $k$ is a field, then $k[x]$ is a principal ideal domain. And in a PID, every prime ideal is maximal. But this would be in contradiction with theorem 2.8, since $k[x]$ is Noetherian and PID and therefore $k[x]$ must be Artinian. What goes wrong here?

Comment: The ring $k[x]$ has a certain trivial prime ideal that is not maximal. Actually all PIDs have that trivial ideal.

Comment: You are correct that if $k$ is a field, that $k[x]$ is a PID, because $k[x]$ is a Euclidean domain, with the degree of the polynomial the Euclidean valuation, and every Euclidean domain is a principal ideal domain

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\cdots (x^3)\subseteq (x^2)\subseteq (x)$ is an infinite decreasing sequence of ideals.

Comment: Is $\left(x^3\right)\subseteq\left(x^2\right)$? Did you mean $\left(x^4\right)\subseteq\left(x^2\right)$?

Comment: $(x^3) \subset (x^2)$, because $(x^2)$ is an ideal of $k[x]$, so by the definition for every $r \in k[x], a \in (x^2), ra \in (x^2)$. In particular, with $r = x$ and $a = x^2$, $x^3 \in (x^2)$.

Answer (score 12):

In a PID, every *nonzero* prime ideal is maximal. But the condition for an artinian ring is that *every* prime ideal must be maximal, even the zero ideal (if it is prime). Therefore, the only PIDs that are artinian are fields.